# Insert in vector after each even value specific number

Tags: c++, vector

I need to insert -20 after each even element, but my code not workint correctly,
what i'm doing wrong?

```
srand(time(NULL));
vector <int> v;

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    v.push_back(rand()%100);
    cout << v[i] << endl;
}


cout << "Vector after inserting new value: \n\n";
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    if (v[i]%2==0)
    {
        v.insert(v.begin()+i, -20);

    }
    cout << v[i] << endl;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Expected result?  Actual result?

Comment: Perhaps std::vector is not the best container for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector <int> v;

v.reserve(15);
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    v.push_back(rand() % 100);
    cout << v[i] << endl;
}


cout << "Vector after inserting new value: \n\n";
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    if (v[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        v.insert(v.begin() + i + 1, -20); // We insert at the next position
        i++; // We make additional increment only if insertion took place
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    cout << v[i] << endl;
}
```

The output (with spaces intead of linebreaks)

```
41 67 34 0 69 24 78 58 62 64 5 45 81 27 61

Vector after inserting new value:

41 67 34 -20 0 -20 69 24 -20 78 -20 58 -20 62 -20 64 -20 5 45 81 27 61
```

Comment: Are we supposed to diff this to the OP's code or could you add a word or two to explain how this solves the problem?

Comment: @mrt sorry, i'm not so fast:/

Answer (score 2):

Using `i++` and `i = i + 1` is not going to end well.

Clearly, you only need to increment `i` twice if you insert an element.

If you want to insert an element just *after* position `i`, then you'll need to use

```
v.insert(v.begin() + 1 + i, ...)
```